# allure report - @Issue,@Issues,@TestCaseID

Tags: allure

Can anyone explain in detail regarding these three annotations -@Issue,@Issues,@TestCaseID for allure reporting .

I have already gone through the documentation link https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Issues.

Can i Use @Issues at a method level , so that i can each issue on to the report for each failure.

it would be great if anyone provide me examples apart from the existing examples in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. **@Issue** and **@Issues** annotations can be placed on both methods and classes. **@Issues** is just a container to link class or case to multiple issues. The main idea is that you specify an issue tracker URL with a placeholder for issue ID, e.g. `http://example.com/issue/%s`. Then you place only issue ID, e.g. `MYPROJECT-314` using these annotations like shown in documentation. During report generation `%s` placeholder in tracker URL will be simply replaced by issue ID and added to report, so report will contain just the following: `http://example.com/issue/MYPROJECT-314`.
2. **@TestCaseID** can only be placed on a method because in our model a single test case is just a method and never a class. But the main idea remains the same - you specify base URL to your test case management system (e.g. [Testlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Quality_Center), [QualityCenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestLink) and so on) and after that Allure report contains a link to test case page.